# Is a noun singular or plural when listing two or more of them that are numbered?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, grammatical-number

I was asked by someone to review a selection of portrait photos and then respond by selecting which one(s) I wanted to have printed. Each photo is labelled "Pose," followed by a letter (i.e., Pose A, Pose B, and so on).

Which response is correct?

Poses D and E

or

Pose D and E

Do I omit the "s"? Does it matter which one I opt for?

Comment: Don’t omit the s. You’re ordering two items.

Comment: If you search for similar things like "Chapter(s) 1-3" or "Paragraph(s) 1 and 2" or "Page(s) 1 and 2", both versions are common with and without "s". Particularly if it's a title, label, etc, as in this case. But this is a duplicate.